# How to databind to a RadioButton property?

Tags: wpf, xaml, mvvm

I have a WPF app that uses MVVMLight.

I am trying to data bind a Radio Button in my UI data entry form. The below XAML works for binding to the Radio Buttons when I'm editing and first display the form, the correct radio button is checked. But when I go to save changes, MySelectedItem.ItemID does not get updated.

How can I get the selected radio button to update MySelectedItem?

```
//View
<StackPanel 
Grid.Row="3" 
Grid.Column="1"
Orientation="Horizontal"
Margin="2,5,2,24" Grid.RowSpan="2">
<RadioButton 
    GroupName="MyGroup"
    Margin="4"
    IsChecked="{Binding Path=MySelectedItem.ItemID, 
        Mode=TwoWay, 
        Converter={StaticResource App_RadioBoolToIntConverter}, 
        ConverterParameter=2}" 
        Content="Choice 1"/>
<RadioButton 
    GroupName="MyGroup"
    Margin="4"
    IsChecked="{Binding Path=MySelectedItem.ItemID, 
        Mode=TwoWay, 
        Converter={StaticResource App_RadioBoolToIntConverter}, 
        ConverterParameter=1}" 
        Content="Choice 2"/>
</StackPanel>

//View Model
public const string MySelectedItemPropertyName = "MySelectedItem";

private MyModelObject _MySelectedItem = null;

/// <summary>
/// Sets and gets the MySelectedItem property.
/// Changes to that property's value raise the PropertyChanged event. 
/// </summary>
public MyModelObject MySelectedItem
{
    get
    {
        return _MySelectedItem;
    }
    set
    {
        if (_MySelectedItem == value)
        {
            return;
        }
        RaisePropertyChanging(MySelectedItemPropertyName);
        _MySelectedItem = value;
        RaisePropertyChanged(MySelectedItemPropertyName);
    }
}


//Converter App_RadioBoolToIntConverter
    public class RadioBoolToIntConverter : System.Windows.Data.IValueConverter
    {
        public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
        {
            int integer = (int)value;
            if (integer == int.Parse(parameter.ToString()))
                return true;
            else
                return false;
        }

        public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            return parameter;
        }

    }
```

Comment: Code for `App_RadioBoolToIntConverter`?

Comment: No one can tell you unless you show all of the relevant code.

Comment: I added my converter class

Comment: Did you try `UpdateTrigger=PropertyChange` in binding?

Comment: where is your code for `MyModelObject`, have you defined `ItemID` as property? The code you are showing should just work.

Comment: Ok, I solved this. In the Create method, I wasn't setting MySelectedItem to new MySelectedItem(). When this object is null, it won't bind correctly.